# Why dont we have GET call in SOAP?

Tags: web-services, post, soap, get

Why don't we have a `GET`  call in `SOAP`?

We only send `POST` requests with `SOAP`.Why..?

Answer (score 0):

In RESTful APIs, GET, POST, etc. are part of the "method call," so to speak.

However, in SOAP all of the information about the method call is specified in XML.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` is just more practical for transmittng XML objects in the body of a HTTP request or response.  The query string in a `GET` request would be awkward and has limitations.

However, `SOAP 1.2` supports `GET` for certain requests.  This means you can take advantage of caching responses.

`SOAP` is also not bound to any underlying transport architecture (like HTTP).  That means it could be used on top of `SMTP` for example.

See the section on http binding for more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#soapinhttp